# Сортировка по массиву объектов по ключам с массива

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

У меня есть форма. На которой есть услуги. Пользователь выбирает услуги (их может быть от 1 до 20).
И с этой формы приходит массив значений **['услуга-1','услуга-2','услуга-3'].**

На сайте есть карточки услуг. Для карточек я получаю массив объектов с json.

```
[{
"name": "газель тент",
"carryingCapacity": "2 тонны",
**"mover": "грузчики",** 
"raiseToFloor"; "поднять на этаж"
 },
{"name": "газель удлиненная ",
 "carryingCapacity": "3 тонны",
}].
```

Мне нужно перебрать массив объектов на точное вхождение услуг те что пришли массивом с формы.
И получить отсортированый массив объектов.

Смисл в чем вот пользователь заходит открывает мою форму. Выберет те услуги что ему нужны.
После чего ему выводит карточки только те в которых есть все те услуги.

На данный момент у меня вот такой цыкл

```
      (Object.values(data).map(e =>{
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if(Object.values(e).includes(result[i])){
    out[out.length] = e;
  }
}
}));
```

Но он сортирует только по одному вхождению.
Например если я отмечу 2 услуги мне выведет 2 карточки
В одной карточке будет одна услуга а во второй вторая услуга.
Но мне нужно чтоб оно выводило только те карточки в которые предоставляют обе услуги
Массив услуг я могу получать как

```
['грузчики','такелажники'].
```

или же можно получить

```
 ['movers','rigging'].
```

А эти поля есть ключами объекта

```
 [{ 
"name": "газель тент", 
"carryingCapacity": "2 тонны", 
**"mover": "грузчики"**,
 "raiseToFloor"; "поднять на этаж" },
 {"name": "газель удлиненная ",
 "carryingCapacity": "3 тонны", 
**"rigging":'такелажники'** }].
```

Comment: где пример массива услуг ? в каком из полей "карточки" храняться "услуги" ?

Comment: Массив услуг я могу получать как ['грузчики','такелажники']. или же можно получить ['movers','rigging']. А эти поля есть ключами объекта  [{
"name": "газель тент",
"carryingCapacity": "2 тонны",
**"mover": "грузчики",** 
"raiseToFloor"; "поднять на этаж"
 },
{"name": "газель удлиненная ",
 "carryingCapacity": "3 тонны",
**"rigging":'такелажники'**
}].

Comment: дополните вопрос, и ето все в вопрос внесите, и отформатируйте нормально код в вопросе, можете даже сделать пример кода, которий можно запустить

Comment: Можете мне помочь?

Comment: `['грузчики','такелажники']` вот где именно ети поля надо искать ?

Comment: эти поля мы ищем в массиве объектов

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю: в массиве вы получаете или набор нужных ключей объекта, или набор нужных значений.  И нужно выбрать те объекты, у которых есть или все ключи из массива, или все значения из массива?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, можно так:

```js
'use strict';

const cards = [
  {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
  },
  {
    c: 3,
    d: 4,
    e: 5,
  },
];

const options1 = ['b', 'c'];
const options2 = [2, 3];

console.log(filter(cards, options1));
console.log(filter(cards, options2));

function filter(arrayOfCards, arrayOfOptions) {
  return arrayOfCards.filter((card) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(card);
    const values = Object.values(card);
    return arrayOfOptions.every(
      option => keys.includes(option) || values.includes(option)
    );
  });
}
```